# How can I install CPLEX for Python so I can access it via Jupyter?

Tags: python, api, installation, jupyter, cplex

I have already downloaded the CPLEX Studio. I am an absolute command prompt beginner, so following IBM's tutorials to install the API is proving to be very difficult. I want to get to the point where I can import cplex in Jupyter. I have reviewed other similar questions, but those answers are difficult to understand (for me). Is anyone able to explicitly explain how to do this in layman's terms?

Answer (score 2):

If you can provide your OS, CPLEX version, python version and how you run jupyter,
I can provide you the exact commands to run.

You basically want to have a command prompt setup with the same python interpreter
you use for jupyter. Assuming CPLEX 12.10, you want to

```
$ cd $CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR1210/python/VERSION/PLATFORM
$ python setup.py install
```

(where VERSION is your python version, likely 3.6 or 3.7, PLATFORM is your OS platform)

For reference the doc is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html

Comment: I run Jupyter with Anaconda (I think).. the python commands don't do anything but pull up the microsoft store for me to install python

Comment: this is the directory where it is installed:"...CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64"

Comment: From the path you have: "...CPLEX_Studio_Community1210\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64" it looks like you are using the community edition. You can save yourself a lot of trouble by installing cplex CE from PyPI. You can do that by creating a new notebook, then just `!pip install cplex` in an empty cell. After that, restart your jupyter kernel and you are set up. (You need to do that only once)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the installation from a jupyter notebook.
Just create a new notebook, then:

If you are using the Community Edition, just create a cell with:

```
!pip install cplex
```

If you want to use an edition already downloaded on your disk, create a cell with:

```
%cd "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64"
!pip install .
```

You need to do this only once.
After pip finishes, you just need to restart your jupyter.